# Paginating a table in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I already have a table that renders my data.  But there can be as many as 1000 rows in the table.

Right now, the dataprovider component sends date to the table component via props.  What's the best way to start pagination?  Should I still fetch all the data at once, as is currently the case?  If so, where do I store it? Keep it in memory and take slices as needed?  Or somehow use query params for the the number of records to fetch (0 - 24, 25 - 49, etc)?

Comment: server side pagination is best in this case. you can use `react-table` to achieve this.  You can create a custom component also with the `react-table`, doing this can give customized styles.

Comment: Don't go in the trajectory of fetching the entire data at once, it will scale poorly. If you're in the infrastructure level start building already with asynchronous requests in mind. Don't waste data-traffic loading things the user isn't seeing, it will be way better and there are plenty of tools to handle this server-side connected to front-end side.

Comment: In my opinion, If 1000 rows is the max you are expecting, I don't see any issue in fetching all at once provided the end users are using relatively new machines. However if it goes beyond 5k suppose, that would make the UI laggy. As suggested by co members , you can fetch a subset of results if the data provider or backend supports it. react-table is a good option if you are using most of the features provided by it else go for your own table. From the implementation part you can maintain a main state with all 1000 records and a derived state which stores the records in view

Answer (score 0):

Returning all the data in one response could be too large, this depends on the size of each item. If the size of the response is small, you can simply request all the data and do the pagination on the UI. You can use [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) to do this.

If the response is too heavy (time-consuming), you have to implement pagination on your server. Then you can use [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) to seamlessly integrate the pagination to the UI.

The approach you use to paginate it is up to you, here are a few ways you can do it in: [API pagination guide](https://www.apiacademy.co/lessons/2015/08/api-design-lesson-303-pagination)